# Is it possible to set localstorage from backend to frontend react js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, express

I am creating an affiliate functionality on my eCommerce website, I have created link generate functionality, My main concept is if any user buys anything from the generated links the main user who created the URL will get a commission.  I cannot be able to store the short generated links in the local storage of a user since when they click on these generated links, they are redirected directly to the targeted page. so I am trying to get the short generated URL from my node js backend. I am using `node-localstorage` package but it not working.

**My expectation is** when a user clicks on the generated short link, the generated link will be stored into the local storage anyhow from the frontend or backend.

Please note: the generated link will be shared on many platforms so I want before the user goes to the targeted page the short link will be stored into the local storage because if the user goes to the targeted page the short URL is removed automatically.

This is my frontend code: before executing this useEffect the backend redirects to the targeted page.

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
        setLoadings(true)
        fetch(`http://localhost:5000/findUrl/${path}`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                if (data.isUrlTrue) {
                    localStorage.setItem('affiliate', path)
                }
            })
            .finally(() => setLoadings(false))
    }, [path])
```

This is my backend code which is not working.

```
  app.get('/:shortUrl', async (req, res) => {
            const shortenUrl = await bicycleAffiliateLinksCollection.findOne({ short: req.params.shortUrl })
            if (shortenUrl === null) return res.sendStatus(404)
            // shortenUrl.clicks++
            // shortenUrl.save()

            localStorage.setItem('affliate', "asdasd");
            res.redirect(shortenUrl.full)
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the short URL in the local storage *before* the browser follows the link:

```html
<a href="short_url" onclick='localStorage.setItem("affiliate","short_url")'>Buy it!</a>
```

Comment: this will not work I think, the generated link will be shared into social media if anyone clicks on that link he will be redirected to the targeted page but I want before the user goes to the targeted page the short URL will be stored in the local storage because if the user goes the targeted page the short URL removed from the URL automatically.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your concept. Are you saying that the short URL works only once (whoever first clicks on it wins)? But why do you need to store it in the local storage, then?

Comment: Actually no, the short URLs stay forever into the database, suppose I have generated this URL `mywebsite.com/product-1234` to `mywebsite.com/abcd`, I SO the problem is if any user click on it from any platform the short URL is removed automatically, and the actual link shows  `mywebsite.com/product-1234` so I can't be able to get that short link which is `abcd`

Comment: Can you include the short link in the long one? The short link `http://mywebsite.com/abcd` would redirect to `http://mywebsite.com/product-1234?short=abcd`.

Comment: yea, I was thinking to do this using a search query we can get short URLs, Thanks bro